# Write a function `smallest_absent t` that returns the smallest natural integer not present in `l`

Tags: compiler-errors, ocaml

Write a signature function `smallest_absent : int_list -> int` such as the call `smaller_absent l` returns the smallest natural integer not present in `l`

```
let smallest_absent l =
match l with
|[] -> 0
|_ -> let m = ref (0,false) in
        while !m.(1) = false do
        if (mem l m.(0)) then !m.(1) := true ;
        else incr(m.(0));
        done;
    !m.(0);;
```

error:

```
> while !m.(1) = false do
this expression is of type int * bool, but is used with the type 'a vect>`
```

I would like to know what's wrong with my code. And if it is correct conceptually. Thank you.

Comment: Fron the [help/on-topic]: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

Comment: I think it is ok now.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with your code other than just this error and the solution @gallais points to. I'd recommend starting smaller and buliding it incrementally, to avoid being overwhelmed by errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type error says it all: you're trying to use a vector lookup `_.(1)` on something that is a tuple of an `int` and a `bool`.

The function you are looking for is [`snd : 'a * 'b -> 'b`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALsnd).

Similarly, instead of writing `m.(0)`, you should write `fst !m` using [`fst : 'a * 'b -> 'a`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALfst)

Answer (score 4):

You already have your answer, so it's more like remark or suggestion.

Maybe conceptually it's correct, but it has a terrible complexity and it's always a pain to see loops in ocaml program (especially in such simple one). I suggest you to think more in terms of recursion.

It's much simpler to work with sorted list (and without duplicates), in this case you just need to find first `i` that `l[i] != i`:

```
let smallest_absent l =
  let l = List.sort_uniq compare l in
  let rec f i = function
    | [] -> i
    | h::t -> if h = i then f (i + 1) t
              else i in
  f 0 l
```

And you can imagine further optimizations.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, that was what I was looking for the most.